# jenkins exit status not zero error (status code 125)

Tags: jenkins, ssh

At some point while operating Jenkins, I spit out status 125 and no error message appears. I can't find the error for #125.

The ssh forwarding test between the deployment server and the main server passed.

---

SSH: Connecting from host [ip-122.222.222]

SSH: Connecting with configuration [test2] ...

SSH: EXEC: completed after 7,807 ms

SSH: Disconnecting configuration [test2] ...

ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [125]]

Finished: UNSTABLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer.
The answer was on the distribution server, a Docker-related error, and an error occurred on the distribution server, so only code for the error appeared on the Jenkins server.

If you get an error about #125, check the docker on the distribution server.

Comment: Thank you so much! I cannot run docker command as follows "docker stop service-name" due to there is no running docker container. Please try any docker command to find the docker error

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ssh man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) :

> ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an error occurred.

So 125 might be the exit status of the command you were executing through ssh or just (assuming your shell is Bash), that the operation was cancelled. See [Bash error codes](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-bash-exit-status-set-exit-statusin-bash/)